# Keycloak instances with the same database are out of sync

Tags: synchronization, keycloak

From our previous request [Hide Keycloak admin console from public access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721075/hide-keycloak-admin-console-from-public-access) we managed to get two Keycloak instances working with the same database.

The instances are each running as docker services with different configurations, but with the same database connection.

Why two instances?

1. one for public access without admin login and other restrictions
2. one with private access for administrative work

Now we have the problem, if we make changes in 2. (private administration), then the changes in the first instance take effect only after a restart.

What do we need to do to make the changes from the administrative instance take effect directly in the first public instance?

For example, adding attributes to users via the second instance will not take effect in the first instance until the docker service is restarted.

What would be the best practice here to avoid a restart?
Events, hooks or specific cache configurations to synchronize the two instances?

Unfortunately, we could not find more detailed informations on this topic.